# gksu not working

Tags: nautilus, sudo, gksu, administrator

```
gksu nautilius
```

Running the above or trying to run the nautlius script -'**browse as root**' gives the following error

```
/home/borax12/.gtkrc-2.0:6: error: scanner: unterminated string constant

(gksu:3914): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**sudo** seems to work fine ,but why is the **gksu** password prompt not working ,the moment i type a letter in the passowrd prompt box ,it exits and give the above error.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Was it suppose to be `gksu nautilus` ?

Comment: sorry for the typo @penreturn

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have got some customisations in `.gtkrc-2.0` that are making the graphical display box for `gksu` abort. The error message refers to these theme engines, so you could temporarily disable that `.gtkrc` file, as this one in the home folder is not installed by default anyway, but contains user's tweaks for various things.

Open a terminal (by default it opens in your home folder) and run the following to **rename** the file, but not delete it:

```
mv .gtkrc-2.0 .gtkrc-2.0.backup
```

You could also remove `.gksu.lock` so you have a clean start and then test `gksudo` or `gksu` by running

```
gksu nautilus
```

If that now works, you need to examine your `.gtkrc` file to see what the problem was and identify if you need to use it, or what customisations you can safely keep.

If you want to **reinstate** the `.gtkrc` file, simply run (from your home folder)

```
mv .gtkrc-2.0.backup .gtkrc-2.0
```

Comment: well @Mik thanks for the help , my gtkrc was all fine ,it was some alterations i had done to my bashrc that was causing the problem .

I had tried changing the PS1 to look different but ended up screwing this gksu thing